# SQLAlchemy session cannot handle query.update() of primary key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have Ords of Subs as follows:

```
class Ord(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ords'
    id    = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    subs = relationship('Sub', back_populates='ord', cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan")

class Sub(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'subs'
    oid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('ords.id', onupdate="cascade", ondelete="cascade"), primary_key=True)
    id  = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Let's say I want to increment id of Sub (part of PK) by 10:

```
self.session.query(Sub).filter(and_(Sub.oid==2, Sub.id > 1)).update({Sub.id: Sub.id + 10})
```

This works and produces desired result. But when I run the same command again it raises the following:

> ObjectDeletedError: Instance 'Sub at 0x197daf597b8' has been deleted, or its row is otherwise not present.

I tried to refresh my objects in session and even `session.expire_all()` -- nothing helps.

How do I make my SQLAlchemy session whole again?

P.S.: Generating a new session from the session factory and substituting in place of self.session above "solves" the issue and permits to run the query again... repeatedly. So sounds like my original session is flawed somehow.

P.P.S.: Here's a low-level log that reproduces the problem:

```
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=c.engine)
ses1=session_factory()

ses1.query(Sub).filter(and_(Sub.oid==2, Sub.id>1)).update({Sub.id: Sub.id + 1})
ses1.commit()
# OK

ses1.query(Sub).filter(and_(Sub.oid==2, Sub.id>1)).update({Sub.id: Sub.id + 1})
ses1.commit()
# OK

sub0 = ses1.query(Ses).filter_by(oid=2, id=26).one()
sub0
# Sub(2, 26)

ses1.query(Sub).filter(and_(Sub.oid==2, Sub.id>1)).update({Sub.id: Sub.id + 1})
ses1.commit()
# OK

sub0
# ObjectDeletedError

ses1.expire_all()
sub0
# ObjectDeletedError

ses1.query(Sub).filter(and_(Sub.oid==2, Sub.id>1)).update({Sub.id: Sub.id + 1})
# ObjectDeletedError

del sub0
sub0
# NameError: name 'sub0' is not defined

ses1.query(Sub).filter(and_(Sub.oid==2, Sub.id>1)).update({Sub.id: Sub.id + 1})
# ObjectDeletedError
```

So it appears that reference to sub0 becomes invalid and there is no way to correctly resolve it now. On the other hand, I don't explicitly keep the reference anywhere in my code -- it is an SQLAlchemy internal error. Even if session.refresh() does not cure it, session.expore_all() definitely ought to.

**Solution, credit to @Ilja Everilä:**

```
ses1.query(Sub).filter(and_(Sub.oid==2, Sub.id>1)).update({Sub.id: Sub.id + 1}, 
        synchronize_session='fetch')
```

This still invalidated my sub0 reference, but at least now the session stays in one piece, and `subs` relationship stays up to date as well.

Comment: You might try using other `synchronize_session` settings in `Query.update()`, but all in all an ORM is probably not going to be very happy about changing identities, esp. one that keeps an internal identity map, such as SQLA. Having to update primary key values also sounds a bit odd.

Comment: @ Ilja Everilä I am using using natural keys (https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3922066/SQL-Server-Natural-Key-Verses-Surrogate-Key.htm) they make more sense in my environment. `synchronize_session='fetch'` solved the issue, thank you. 'evaluate' setting did not change anything, not sure what it is for.

Comment: "evaluate" is the default and it avoids the roundtrip to the DB that "fetch" has to do. In other words it applies the filters and updates the objects in the current session in Python. Also the names of your columns did not quite read like a natural key, so hence the confusion.